# Shared preferences in Native vs Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences

My flutter app has a native component to it. This native component is using `platform.invokeMethod`. In this native component I save a few things to shared prefs using the code

```
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("foo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
sharedPrerences.putString(...
```

Now, I want to read from this shared preference file from my flutter / dart code. But the API does not have a way for me to specify the shared preference file name (`foo`). I can only do this

```
SharedPreference.getInstance().getString(..
```

How do can I solve this?

Comment: what do you mean by "API does not have a way for me to specify the shared preference file name (foo)" what exactly are you trying to do with `SharedPreference`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using the [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)-plugin on the Flutter side. That only accesses a single file whose name is [hard-coded](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/136f49b3e8ec8f96e222a71f17b32a16e9e3e649/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences_android/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/sharedpreferences/MethodCallHandlerImpl.java#L37) in the plugin.

Instead of saving the preferences in the native android side, you could instead return them from the `invokeMethod` to Flutter, and then use the plugin to save them.

And - although not the most elegant solution - you could write the preferences on the android side into the same file the plugin is using:  [`"FlutterSharedPreferences"`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/136f49b3e8ec8f96e222a71f17b32a16e9e3e649/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences_android/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/sharedpreferences/MethodCallHandlerImpl.java#L37). This would probably involve also calling [reload](https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences/reload.html) on the flutter side after the write to make the plugin refresh its local values.

Comment: wow, thanks. why would the plugin hard code the name

Comment: Tried with `FlutterSharedPreferences` in the native code. And I did a `reload` in the flutter code. But the update does not reflect on the flutter side.